# Android: unresponsive thread when a new activity for result is started

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, surfaceview

I am new to Android so I am making a coloring book app just to get myself acquainted to android programming. I have looked up my problem extensively and implemented the solutions but still no progress.

I have an activity 'ColoringActivity' which calls a class 'PaintView' which extends surfaceview. I am trying to update the canvas in a separate thread. I also have a button in the layout which takes the user to another activity for picking colors. The problem is that when the user returns after choosing the color, the canvas becomes empty and I cant draw on the canvas anymore. I think i somehow loose the thread in between activities and although the thread is running in the background, I have no access to it.

I read on this forum that I must implement pause() and resume() methods in the thread class and basically kill the thread when I go to another activity and restart it when I return. Also I read I have to override onPause() and onResume() method in activity class and construct the surfaceview in onResume() so that it is constructed every time user returns to this activity.

I am sorry if it doesnt make much sense because I am lost as well.

My 'ColoringActivity':

```
package com.ali.coloryourself;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ColoringActivity extends Activity {

private static final int COLOR_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static String file;
public static Bitmap bitmap;
BitmapFactory.Options options;
PaintView paintView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    file = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");

//      paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.drawingSurface);


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.drawingSurface);
    paintView.getThread().resume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    paintView.getThread().pause();
    super.onPause();
}

public void pickColor(View v) {
    paintView.getThread().pause();
    Intent colorIntent = new Intent(this, ColorPickerActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(colorIntent, COLOR_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == COLOR_REQUEST_CODE) {
            int color = data.getIntExtra("Color", -1);
//              paintView.getPaint().setColor(color);
        }
    }

}

}
```

My 'PaintView' class:

```
package com.ali.coloryourself;

import android.R.color;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

class PaintView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Canvas canvas;
private PaintThread thread;
private Path path = new Path();

private Bitmap bitmap;

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    setThread(new PaintThread(holder));
}

class PaintThread extends Thread {
    private boolean mRun;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private int mMode;

    public static final int STATE_PAUSE = 2;
    public static final int STATE_RUNNING = 4;

    public PaintThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mRun) {
            try {
                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) {
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1,
                                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    }
                }
                doDraw(canvas);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean b) {
        mRun = b;
    }

    public void pause() {
            if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING)
                setState(STATE_PAUSE);
    }

    public void resume() {
        setState(STATE_RUNNING);
    }

    public void setState(int mode) {
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            mMode = mode;
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Log.d("Touch", "I am touching");
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // nothing to do
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (getThread().getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
        getThread().setRunning(true);
        getThread().start();
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    getThread().setRunning(false);
    getThread().resume();
    while (retry) {
        try {
            getThread().join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

public Paint getPaint() {
    return paint;
}

public void setPaint(int color) {
    this.paint.setColor(color);
}

public PaintThread getThread() {
    return thread;
}

public void setThread(PaintThread thread) {
    this.thread = thread;
}

}
```

my 'activity_draw.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="pickColor"
    android:text="Pick Color" />

<com.ali.coloryourself.PaintView
    android:id="@+id/drawingSurface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know I am missing some very basic thread concept. I need to allow the user to pick color and return and be able to continue drawing. I will be extremely grateful for your help.

Comment: The Activity and Surface lifcycles aren't tightly bound.  See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity .  In some cases you want to tear things down, in others its reasonable to retain a reference in a static field.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer although I am not sure if it is a good programming practice. I found out that my surface view and thread were created once 'ColoringActivity' was created and destroyed every time 'ColoringActivity' went to background. But once 'ColoringActivity' was restarted and resumed, surface view and thread were not recreated. So i moved the following line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);
```

to onResume() method and now I can draw on the canvas every time. Now I just need to save the canvas and re load it when the activity comes back on to start off the coloring where the user left it.